# React state management with redux vs lifting state up

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

After reading reacts lifting state up, it made sense how shared state was held by the parent and it would then pass it as props and re-render as needed. However with redux we can have state in the store. Then is it okay to violate the top down data flow and have sibling components interact via redux? Or they should still update the parent state and have the parent re-render them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If siblings are interacting via Redux, the communication is still top down (because they aren't communicating with each other — they're communicating with Redux).

1. Sibling A dispatches a redux action
2. Some reducer updates the state
3. Sibling B updates based on the new state

Using `connect` from `react-redux` eliminates the need to manually pass props down through an entire chain of components.

Ultimately, where and how you manage state in an app depends on a lot of different factors. There's no right answer here. I've seen both strategies used within the same app.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the question and answer as of when I post my answer here, I'd like to further add to Bryan's statement using the official [Redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store):

> Prefer having more UI components subscribed to the Redux store and reading data at a more granular level. This typically leads to better UI performance, as fewer components will need to render when a given piece of state changes.
>
> For example, rather than just connecting a `<UserList>` component and reading the entire array of users, have `<UserList>` retrieve a list of all user IDs, render list items as `<UserListItem userId={userId}>`, and have `<UserListItem>` be connected and extract its own user entry from the store.
>
> This applies for both the React-Redux `connect()` API and the `useSelector()` hook.